# Python Very Slow After Save

Tags: python, compilation, terminal, save

So this has been happening only recently on my Mac. After saving a Python program I go to the terminal to run it, here is what happens:

1. The terminal tries to run previous saves of the program. To get it to run the most recent save I have to close the window and force quit terminal and restart it. A few months ago I could get it to run the most recent save without even having to close the terminal window.
2. When terminal does run the program, it is extremely slow (on the order of minutes) even on programs with no errors and it runs even longer if there is an error. After this first run, it runs much, much, much faster (on the order of milliseconds).

I know the first time I run the program on terminal it should take a little longer as the file needs to compile. But it is has never taken this long to compile Python files. Even on simple hello world files it can take a full minute to compile...

Does anyone have any insight into these two anomalies?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to write these programs?  Before you run, if you `ls -l`, does the modified date match what you expect it to?

Comment: You could try a few different things to debug this. Check your dot files to see if there might be something running in a pre exec hook. If you can, you should try using a different terminal program to see if that helps. This won't fix the issue! :)